# $I_n+\lambda E_{12}$ together with permutation matrices generate all matrices of the form $I_n+\lambda E_{ij}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, permutation-matrices

Let $K$ be a field. For $1\leq i,j\leq n$ such that $i\ne j$ and $\lambda\in K$, let $B_{ij}(\lambda):=I_n+\lambda E_{ij}$, where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $1$ and is $0$ otherwise. I want to show that all matrices of the form $B_{ij}(\lambda)$ are generated by $B_{12}(\lambda)$ and permutation matrices.

My idea is to show that by left and right multiplication by transposition matrices it is possible to turn $B_{12}(\lambda)$ into $B_{ij}(\lambda)$. Multiplying $B_{12}(\lambda)$ by $M(\tau_{2i})$ on the left and $M(\tau_{1j})$ on the right gives a matrix whose $(i,j)$-th entry is $\lambda$. Then by multiplying this matrix by transposition matrices not moving the $i$-th row or the $j$-th column we can arrive at $B_{ij}(\lambda)$.

The problem is that I am not sure how to make this proof rigorous. Should I be using induction? Any suggestions to get me started?

**Edit:**

Note that $\tau_{ij}$ denotes the transposition with support $\{i,j\}$ and $M(\tau_{ij})$ denotes its matrix.

Comment: You can show this by showing any matrix $B_{ij}(\lambda)$ can be obtained by multiplying $B_{12}(\lambda)$ with appropriate permutation matrices. Hint: multiplying a matrix $A$ with a permutation matrix will permute rows (or columns) of $A$.

Comment: @mathmath Obviously one has to multiply by permutation matrices... My question concerns the choice of the permutation matrices; i.e. given arbitrary $i\ne j$, how does one choose the permutation matrices to multiply $B_{12}(\lambda)$ by to get $B_{ij}(\lambda)$. In a concerte case, one can easily figure this out. But how does one prove it generally?

Comment: Please read the hint. You should try to do some experiments with multiplying a permutation matrix (to the left and to the right) with a matrix $A$ and see what rows or columns of matrix $A$ that the multiplication swaps.

Comment: @mathmath Again, I have no trouble doing this in a concrete case (i.e. when I replace variable $i,j,n$ with integers). I am not able to discern the algorithm that specifies the process generally. You don't even need to work with arbitrary permutations; transpositions alone should be enough.

Comment: If you know how to do for all $i,j$ then it is enough for a proof. Why do you need induction? The logic is for every $n$ and every $i,j$ you know how to write $B_{ij}$ as product of $B_{12}$ and permutation matrices. That's the proof. You have already done it.